# Can I restrict inheritance to package without using 'default'?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have some classes that I need to be able to extend within the same package. But I don't want for anyone else outside of my package to extend my classes. Classes in other packages need to be able to call my classes so I cannot use 'default'.

Is there any way (maybe through an interface) that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

If you make your constructors package local, it can only be extended in the same package however public members can be accessed in any class if it is a public class.

Comment: This is a great solution because it would also allow the base class to be visible outside of the package.

Comment: I need for classes in other packages to be able to instantiate my class. Wouldn't making all constructors local prevent that?

Comment: You could use factory methods to allow them to be instantiated.

Comment: I think you meant "can only be extended in the same *package*", right? But very nice solution, thanks.

Comment: @rolve Thank you for being the first to point this out after 2 years. ;)

Answer (score 6):

I'd do this by creating a base class with `default` visibility, then extend it with a `public final` class that external classes can call into but not extend. For example:

```
class MyBase {
    public void doSomething() { ... }
}

public final class PublicBase extends MyBase { }

class ExtendedBase {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface for use of the class and a factory class that would return concrete implementations, both of which would be public and therefore visible outside the package.  Then create your concrete classes with default visibility.